# Some subfolders on NTFS share randomly disappear and then reappear

Tags: windows, network-share, ntfs, public-folders

As the title suggest,
One user has reported that most subfolders of a NTFS share keep disappearing and then reappearing randomly.

The share has 7 folders however 6 of them keep disappearing randomly.
Nothing changes and they just reappear.

The user has NTFS permissions and share permissions
The user is wired to the network
There are no obvious event logs either.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: We need more information about the setup.  The share is located on a server I assume?  What version of Windows is the server running? What version of Windows is the client running? How are the files shared (CIFS/SMB I assume)?  Are other users experiencing the same issues?

Comment: Sorry yes, 2008 R2 and Windows 8.1 via SMB,
Just this one user reporting the issue too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable auditing on the folders and in the security policies on the computer where the share is hosted to be able to determine when the folders are deleted and what account is deleting them. After that is enabled, you should see 4663 events in the Security event log when they are deleted.

[image]

Comment: Hi Greg, the folders aren't being deleted, rather they just disappear from the share for a random period of time before reappearing