# Network shared Folder randomly disappears for a user

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, windows-10, share

We are running a Windows 2012 Server as DC and Fileserver that is accessed by Windows 10 Clients.

The rights management for our shared folders is handled through security groups.

A few weeks ago a user said he couldn't see a specific folder anymore, while the other folders seemed to be there as always. The folders are all in the same share folder, only separated through said security groups.

After checking the access rights, which were unchanged, I tried accessing said folder via his Explorer (\\srv\share) and *net use*. Both said the folder wouldn't exist or he was missing the appropriate rights.

After a reboot the folder reappeared. However, it still disappears randomly. It's only about this single user and only this single folder.

Any thoughts?

This thread [Some subfolders on NTFS share randomly disappear and then reappear](https://serverfault.com/questions/734924/some-subfolders-on-ntfs-share-randomly-disappear-and-then-reappear)
didn't provide any usable answers.

Comment: Got an AV that scan remote share ?

Comment: Is "access based enumeration" enabled on that share? Does the problem subside if you disable ABE?

Comment: If this works with ABE disabled, the problem would not be ABE, but a permission problem most likely caused by a degraded AD replication.

Comment: Well, that's something to check. We actually implemented a second DC to the domain recently. Disabling ABE is not something we can do, since we very much need it. But I'll check for replication errors, thanks so far.

Comment: The Event log doesn't show any recent Errors. I also checked repadmin /showrepl, it outputs "successful" on everything. Any more hints for troubleshooting?

Comment: @yagmoth555: Our clients don't scan network folders, we have an AV on the server though. But if that was the problem, I think more users should be affected, right?